# iOS How to find network data usage programatically

Tags: ios, networking

I'd like my iOS app to report how much data it has downloaded (over WiFi or network).

Are there any API's for this?

Answer (score -1):

Try this-

```
- (NSArray *)getDataCounters
{
BOOL   success;
struct ifaddrs *addrs;
const struct ifaddrs *cursor;
const struct if_data *networkStatisc; 

int WiFiSent = 0;
int WiFiReceived = 0;
int WWANSent = 0;
int WWANReceived = 0;

NSString *name=[[[NSString alloc]init]autorelease];

success = getifaddrs(&addrs) == 0;
if (success) 
{
    cursor = addrs;
    while (cursor != NULL) 
    {
        name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",cursor->ifa_name];
        NSLog(@"ifa_name %s == %@\n", cursor->ifa_name,name);
        // names of interfaces: en0 is WiFi ,pdp_ip0 is WWAN 

        if (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK) 
        {
            if ([name hasPrefix:@"en"]) 
            {
                networkStatisc = (const struct if_data *) cursor->ifa_data;
                WiFiSent+=networkStatisc->ifi_obytes;
                WiFiReceived+=networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes;
                NSLog(@"WiFiSent %d ==%d",WiFiSent,networkStatisc->ifi_obytes);
                NSLog(@"WiFiReceived %d ==%d",WiFiReceived,networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes);
            }

            if ([name hasPrefix:@"pdp_ip"]) 
            {
                networkStatisc = (const struct if_data *) cursor->ifa_data;
                WWANSent+=networkStatisc->ifi_obytes;
                WWANReceived+=networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes;
                NSLog(@"WWANSent %d ==%d",WWANSent,networkStatisc->ifi_obytes);
                NSLog(@"WWANReceived %d ==%d",WWANReceived,networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes);
            } 
        }

        cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
    }

    freeifaddrs(addrs);
}       

return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:WiFiSent], [NSNumber numberWithInt:WiFiReceived],[NSNumber numberWithInt:WWANSent],[NSNumber numberWithInt:WWANReceived], nil];
}
```

Comment: that code will get you the data for the handset as a whole -- not the app.